# Reset individual app settings

Tags: applications, settings, crashes

Something happened on my HTC Tattoo (V1.6) that caused lots of apps to crash on start-up. I think it may have been due to their settings getting corrupted somehow, but I don't know what caused that.

I've been able to get some working again by uninstalling them and then installing them again. Obviously, I lost any set-up by doing this.

Is it possible to reset the settings for a given app? I don't even know where they are stored. Is it in an `.xxx` type file as on Linux? It would be useful to know where they are so I can back them up in future.

Update August 2011: Now it's happening again. Google apps failed first, but then Facebook and last.fm stopped working. Tried clearing data/cache with no improvement. Can't re-install some apps as they are no longer available for 1.6. I do intend to try upgrading when I get time.

Answer (score 3):

As Al says, Settings > Applications > Manage Applications, go to app and press Clear cache seems to do the trick.

Comment: This won't reset the app's settings, it will only clear its cache.

Answer (score 0):

To reset an application's settings, go to `Settings > Apps` and select the desired application.  Then use the buttons on that page to clear the data and the cache.

If the application's settings were synced to a Google account, a Google bug could potentially set them back to the previous settings.  If this happens, just delete the data and cache again.